# Change login/register dropdown to "my account" when user login Bootstrap/PHP

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, session, authentication

I am learning Bootstrap and this is my first front-end project. I have a login/register dropdown menu and the PHP backend logic already implemented with PHP session.

I want to know how to change the login/register dropdown to something like "my account"?

I thought about making a separate page for logged and offline user and using an index.php page to redirect to the correct page. However, I find this solution highly inefficient since this would basicaly be copy/pasting the same page to only change 1 dropdown button.

How should I handle this kind of situation?

Here is the dropdown button:

[image: login form]

Comment: You probably want to use “ajax login”. Either google this term, or review the existing code (e. g. [Wordpress AJAX plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-login/).)

Comment: Thanks! I think that I am getting closer to a solution simply by looking at that example: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_hide_show

Answer (score 0):

You can check the login session and include it to if else. example:

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {
    echo "My Account";
} else {
    echo "<ul><li>Login</li><li>Register</li></ul>";
}
?>
```